# Installing Cordova and Ionic without sudo

Tags: macos, cordova, npm, installation, sudo

I am trying to setup Cordova and Ionic for a project on a MacBook Pro running OS X El Capitan v10.11.4.

The [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html#installing-the-cordova-cli) says to use `sudo npm install -g cordova` which works fine, but with all of the "horror" stories and mixed opinions on using `sudo` out there I tend to just look for a solution that doesn't involved it unless absolutely necessary.

I'm wondering if there is any straight forward way to install both Cordova and Ionic without using `sudo`.  If there is no straight forward way or it is recommended in this case to use `sudo` could someone please explain?

Comment: I'm afraid nothing is straightforward on MacOS.

Answer (score 3):

it will help you

[Install npm packages globally without sudo on OS X and Linux](https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md)